# if i know baseURI and basePath, Is it possible to get params when I access page?

Tags: rest-assured, rest

when you access the homepage, A lot of APIs will be exposed.

But I have the baseURI and BasePath of the API I want.

For Example, When you connect to http://www.example.com, Among various APIs, an api called [http://www.example.com/person/ajaxPersonList?name="Doe"&Age=30](http://www.example.com/person/ajaxPersonList?name=%22Doe%22&Age=30) is also called.

This API has a variety of params

So, if i know baseURI(http://www.example.com) and basePath(person/ajaxPersonList)

Is it possible to get params using restAssured?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

- If you are working on this project, you can access API document. You can see the params that each API is using.
- If you are investigating the web app online, you have to try and error.